# How to have multiple galleries magnific pop-up in the same section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I have been trying to make a website where there is a section called "Fotos", or Photos. Inside this section, there are links to "Ambiente", "Pratos" and "Bebidas", which are basically "Ambience", "Dishes" and "Drinks".
Now, before I had this, the magnific pop-up worked for a `<div class="gallery-images">`.

Once I implemented it, I've had a few problems.
I can make it work to just one `<div class="gallery-images'>` then it would be just one gallery with all the photos, and the way I made (additional classes) was the only way I've managed to do it.

I've been searching for days on stackoverflow and read the documentation of magnific popup. Although I'm not really good yet at JS, I've tried doing something by myself. I've also changed the class in the magnific pop up snippet to just about anything.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">

<section class="fotos py-6" id="fotos">
    <div class="gallery-section" id="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-images ambiente active"> 
            <a href="img/ambiente1.jpg" class="image">
                <img src="img/ambiente1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-images comidas">
            <a href="img/comidas1.jpg" class="image">
                <img src="img/comidas1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-images bebidas">
            <a href="img/bebidas1.jpg" class="image">
                <img src="img/bebidas1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        <div>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js">
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //magnific popup
    $('.gallery-images').magnificPopup({ 
        type: 'image', 
        delegate: 'a', 
        closeOnContentClick: true, 
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        },
    }); 
});
```

I've tried `.gallery-images .ambiente .active`, `.gallery-images.ambiente.active`, `.gallery-images.ambiente`, `.gallery-images .ambiente`, I've tried to work with `.each(function(){ $(this).indexOf("ambiente") ... }` and such.

I put the ambiente, comidas, bebidas classes because I've worked some code for changing the galleries. The active class is for that as well.

I was expecting to get the magnific pop up to work on every gallery. Instead, it opens up another tab with the image.

Comment: Here is working fine. What is the issue exactly, I didn't get it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man! Is it working with just .gallery-images on the magnific popup?

Comment: My magnific popup isn't working anymore since i've made some changes.

Comment: Before my edit, you didn't close some HTML tags. Please, take care about that. You know, every `<div>` must have a `</div>` to close it. I even forget to fix one there. The popup is working fine in general. For now, I don't know what exactly you are trying to fix  besides those minor adjustments in HTML. I hope it works well now for you.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the help. What happened was I, being a rookie, was making a rookie mistake. I was loading the plugins before I was loading the jQuery. As simple as that. Thanks again for your help!